# How to fix error code "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)" in node.js

Tags: node.js

I am getting the error "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)" in node.js.

```
const replaceTemplate = (temp, product) => {
    let output = temp.replace(/{%PRODUCTNAME%}/g, 'product.name');
    output = temp.replace(/{%IMAGE%}/g, product.image);
    output = temp.replace(/{%PRICE%}/g, product.price);
    output = temp.replace(/{%FROM%}/g, product.from);
    output = temp.replace(/{%NUTRIENTS%}/g, product.nutrients);
    output = temp.replace(/{%QUANTITY%}/g, product.quantity);
    output = temp.replace(/{%DESCRIPTION%}/g, product.description);
    output = temp.replace(/{%ID%}/g, product.id);

    return output
}
const tempOverview = fs.readFileSync('./template-overview.html', 'utf-8')
const tempCard = fs.readFileSync('./template-card.html', 'utf-8')
const tempProduct = fs.readFileSync('./template-product.html', 'utf-8')

const data = fs.readFileSync('./data.json', 'utf-8')
const dataObj = JSON.parse(data)

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    const pathName = req.url //For different pages
    //Overview page
    if(pathName === '/' || pathName === '/overview') {
        res.writeHead(200, { 'content-Type': 'text/html'})

        const cardsHTML = dataObj.map(el => replaceTemplate(tempCard, el)).join('')
        const output = tempOverview.replace('{%PRODUCT_CARDS%}', cardsHTML)
        res.end(output)

    //Product page
    }else if(pathName === '/product'){
        res.writeHead(200, { 'content-Type': 'text/html'})
        res.end(tempProduct)

    //API
    }else if (pathName === '/api'){
        res.writeHead(200, { 'content-Type': 'application/json'})
        res.end(data)

    //Error
    }else{
        res.writeHead(404, { 
            'content-type': 'text/html'    
        })
        res.end('<h1>Page Not Found</h1>')
    }
})

server.listen(3000, '127.0.0.1', () => {
    console.log("listening on port 3000")
})
```

from my research I got that the problem occurs when the port is being used somewhere else but I tried changing the port multiple times but it does not go away.
note: I just started learning node today therefore the problem might be obvious

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible if you could use express js? and then probably use
something like this:

```
const server = app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${PORT} `);
});
```